# IllegalStateException using Ripple Effect Library on Android M Devices

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, ripple, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

Using [this](https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect) `library` to implement `Ripple Effect` and it works just fine **except** on `Android M` devices.

On Android **M** Devices getting `IllegalStateException` that says *Underflow in restore - more restores than saves*

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.ripplethings, PID: 20119
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Underflow in restore - more restores than saves
at android.graphics.Canvas.native_restore(Native Method)
at android.graphics.Canvas.restore(Canvas.java:540)
at com.andexert.library.RippleView.draw(RippleView.java:166)
```

Comment: that library must not having support for M devices

Comment: Look at issues page https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect/issues/76

Comment: the issue is apparently in the library itself. this question seems off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

It seems like a bug in the library itself on Android 6.0, Possible ways to avoid the bug is

1) Use the com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2  library it seems more stable

2) Or you can use place separate layout for 21+ let the Android M handle the ripple itself. Just use the proper ripple holder for layouts and views

3) Or you can modify the library source code itself as per [this](https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect/issues/74) suggestion

4)A fixed version of this library is available @ git and you can use it in your gradle like

```
compile 'com.github.Hitta:RippleEffect:82cf00e551'
repositories {
            ...
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        }
```